# Can you say "I felled the axe"?

Tags: phrase-usage

I realize that an axe is used to fell or cut up trees, but can you say "I felled the axe" when you want to describe the action of swinging the axe down to cut into the tree? Or does that sound strange to English ears?

Comment: You ***heft*** an axe (to ***fell*** a tree). You might also ***wield*** an axe, but that's more likely in figurative contexts such as ***cutting staff / reducing the workforce*** in corporate contexts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you!  Might you say "I swung the axe"?

Comment: "Felling the axe" is like "cutting the knife". Also, don't you swing the axe _sideways_ to fell a tree?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, thanks, I see. Regarding the swinging of an axe you are of course right that it would be sideways to fell a tree, but if you are chopping up an already felled tree, you would swing the axe downwards I guess, and it would be OK to use swing in that way?

Comment: Yes, but you would not say 'fell'. When I have done this it was called 'splitting logs'.

Comment: To cut down a tree. A tree can be felled by an ax. Yes, you swing an ax to use it, right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't use the word *fell* that way.  [**Fell**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fell) means, roughly, "to knock down".  You aren't knocking down the axe.  You fell the *tree*, not the axe.